# How to list all CRS names and IDs in QGIS Python API?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system

I want to get these two lists from QGIS in py plugin/Python interpreter code:

[image]

How to do such a thing in QGIS 3.18?

Comment: Have a look  at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401079/showing-the-bounding-box-for-every-coordinate-system-in-qgis which should get you started

Comment: This will give you lots of data. What is your goal after getting them? We could perhaps give some advice.

Comment: export that list =)

Comment: QGIS has it in a SQLite DB already, you could just query such DB, even without PyQGIS.

Comment: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/database.html#pyproj-database-query-crs-info