# How to check UTM ZONE with lat/lon coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wgs84

How to check UTM ZONE with lat/lon coordinates in QGIS?

The work I need is,
at QGIS

I'm trying to save the location of the XYZ Tile - Google Satellite Map in GeoTIFF with Lat/Lon coordinates.

When I save it as GeoTIFF, I want to make it a UTM coordinate system, but I don't know which UTM zone coordinate system to use because I don't know the UTM zone only with Lat/Lon coordinates.

Comment: This might be helpfull: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::world-utm-grid/explore?location=50.238959%2C-75.505530%2C3.48

Comment: I use UTM Grid Zones of the World to look at Longitudes/Latitudes of all the UTM systems: https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm

Comment: Or load CRS bounding boxes as shown here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401079/showing-the-bounding-box-for-every-coordinate-system-in-qgis filter for utm and intersect them