# Where are the predefined CRS stored in my QGIS installation?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I would like to do a text search through all those. I hope they are simply saved as files somewhere, but I have not been able to find them.

I am on Ubuntu Linux, with QGIS 3.10 installed via apt. But I suppose the question could also be relevant people with a different OS and QGIS version.

Comment: Check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401079/showing-the-bounding-box-for-every-coordinate-system-in-qgis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't saved as a text file, but as a SQLite database file. You can search inside it with a SQL statement, or browsing its data, with [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). You can connect to it with the QGIS Database Administrator too.

The file is:
`/usr/share/qgis/resources/srs.db`

Comment: What is the relation of this srs.db and the Proj crs database that is often in `...share/proj/proj.db`?

Comment: I don't have a /usr/share/proj/proj.db file, so I can't tell you what the relation is.

Comment: What is your `PROJ_LIB` env? Do you have it set, and do you have proj.db there? I have been thinking that Proj requires that file https://proj.org/resource_files.html. This answer claims that proj.db it the one that is used https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375619/qgis-transformation-defined-in-srs-db-tbl-datum-transform-table-not-available-in.

Comment: I do not have the PROJ_LIB variable defined in the installation from the repository (`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe main multiverse restricted`). Is it because of the version? I know my version is old but the question stated that it wouldn't matter. The source code makes mention of being able to update the database from a newer GDAL installation, in the README of https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/resources.

Comment: I do not know really. The comment in the README is from year 2009. The Proj library had a fundamental change in 2018 https://gdalbarn.com/.